# Possible memory leak in Asynchronous ASP.NET Call to a WebService?

Tags: .net, asp.net, memory-leaks, asynchronous

I've created a small class library to asynchronously call a WebService(Fire and Forget. I don't need the result).

In a Windows Form application, the `XXXAsync()` method works fine. But, in a Web Application, the process is locked until the `XXXCompleted` event is fire.

My problem is: I tried to create a Delegate and use the Begin/EndInvoke to call the `XXXAsync()` method. It worked fine, but, the w3wp process seems to be consuming a huge amount of memory. **I'm calling the EndInvoke method properly**. Invoking the `GC.Collect` did not free any memory.

I also tried calling the BeginXXX and EndXXXX Methods from the WebService, and got the same result.

My WebService is a dumb HelloWorld, with a `Thread.Sleep(10000)`.

How to solve this problem? Is there any other way to invoke the webservice asynchronously avoiding those leaks?

Edit[Added the Code below]:

**WebService code**:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class Service1 : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [OneWay]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            return "Hello World ";
        }
    }
```

**ClassLibrary**:

```
    public class HelloLibrary : IDisposable
    {
        private delegate void PerformWhatever();

        public HelloLibrary(){}

        public string Notify()
        {
            PerformWhatever p = new PerformWhatever(OnBeforeBegin);
            p.BeginInvoke(EndInvokeHandler, p);
            return "1";
        }

        private void OnBeforeBegin()
        {
            using (localhost.Service1 s = new localhost.Service1())
            {
                s.HelloWorldAsync();
            }
        }

        private void EndInvokeHandler(IAsyncResult r)
        {
            var delegateInstance = r.AsyncState as PerformWhatever;
            delegateInstance.EndInvoke(r);
        }


        public void Dispose(){}
    }
```

And, in my **Web Application**, I call:

```
            using (HelloLibrary library = new HelloLibrary())
            {
                library.Notify();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the process is locked"?

Comment: Can you show your example code?

Comment: take a look at the asp.net async tasks API

Comment: From "the process is locked", I mean: the WebApplication do not send the response back to the browser, until the WebService has completed it´s work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the result and you own the Web Service you should consider implementing the fire and forget functionality on the web service side through the [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute.aspx) by setting it's [OneWay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute.oneway.aspx) property to true.

> When an XML Web service method has the
>   OneWay property set to true, the XML
>   Web service client does not have to
>   wait for the Web server to finish
>   processing the XML Web service method.
>   As soon as the Web server has
>   deserialized the SoapServerMessage,
>   but before invoking the XML Web
>   service method, the server returns an
>   HTTP 202 status code. A HTTP 202
>   status code indicates to the client
>   that the Web server has started
>   processing the message.